# Can't display the pagination links in blade file - Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel

**Queue.php**

```
class Queue extends Component
{
    public function Data()
    {
        $fgd = FaddddxO::where('seus',$this->stas)
        ->whereNu('achieve_by');
        if ($this->filter == '' && $this->stus != 'x Error') 
        {
            $fax->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
                      ->orwhereDate('d_datetime', Carbon::today());
            });
        } else if ($this->filter == 'ries'){
            $fassssxSss->where('resd_ag','>=',3)->whereNull('archive_by');
        } else if ($this->filter == 'ponse'){
            $favfhdjdfh->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereDate('created_at','<=' ,Carbon::now()->subDays(3))
                      ->orwhereDate('dvkjdvvbfshnd_datetime','<=' ,Carbon::now()->subDays(3));
            })->whereNull('archive_by');
        }
}
```

In the **Data()** function, paginate with **toArray()** method is working. But when trying to populate links() in blade file it's showing the below error.

And this is the error:

> Call to a member function links() on array

Comment: Well, you cast it to an array at `$this->faxStatus = $faxStatusData->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(5)->toArray();` - why?

Comment: Right, but an array doesn't have a `links()` method... Is there something unclear about the error message and why you're receiving it?

Comment: Don't call `->toArray()`? Is there a reason you're doing that? This is your code; you need to know why you're doing what you're doing and recognize when you're doing something that doesn't work.

Comment: What error? Also, you have _a lot_ of code posted; it's tough to wade through it. Try reducing the code in your question to only the relevant stuff, and edit your question with updates instead of posting in the comments.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite explicit, and is caused by this

```php
$this->faxStatus = $faxStatusData->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(5)->toArray();
```

A PHP array does not have any methods to call on it. You need stop at `paginate()` without any further casting if you want to keep the result paginated - by simply stopping with chaining more methods on after `paginate()` - like this

```php
$this->faxStatus = $faxStatusData->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(5);
```

If you need to access the data of the paginated result, you can access that at `$this->faxStatus->items()`, without needing to cast it to an array.

If you - for whichever reason - need to convert it to an array, then you need to assign that to a different property, for example by doing

```php
$this->faxStatus = $faxStatusData->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(5);
$this->faxStatusArray = $this->faxStatus->toArray();
```

And then accessing it as `$this->faxStatusArray`. I would however think that you can achieve the same by accessing `$this->faxStatus->items()`.

Comment: Okay. I don't know which error  that is unless you share it. Its impossible for us to help you if you don't share the exact errors and the relevant code. Keep in mind, you don't do `->pagiante(5)->items()`, that's just the same.. You need to use `$this->faxStatus->items()` where you use the resulting array without the pagination.